# Name Manager error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Public Function updateNameManager(name As Range)
        Dim s As New cStringClass
        Dim a As Range, cell As Range

        On Error GoTo handleIt

        For Each a In name
            s.addAlphaNumeric a.Value
            Set cell = a.Offset(0, 10)

            Debug.Print s.TheString & " " & cell.Address
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Reagents").Names.Add NameLocal:=s.TheString, RefersTo:=cell <---- 1004 error
            s.Clear
        Next a


handleIt:
        Debug.Print "update... " & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
End Function
```

I'm having issues defining a range as a name. Basically this function receives a range say A2:A10. I'll create the name from each range and set a cell to that name.

When the code is run with the error line commented out it'll list the contents of each cell.

Even when I hard code ReferensTo:="=Reagents!$K$2" it still errors out. I guess that I need to reference the sheet in an other way, but cant work it out with 
1004 Application-defined or object-defined error

Thanks in Advance

Comment: think it needs to be cell.address or you may have a name already, try .names.add NameLocal:="TESTINGNAME",.....

Comment: Thanks for quick reply.. Though it didn't though :(

Comment: What's the value of `s.TheString`?

Comment: It holds a string value of the cell and is alpha-numerical only. there are no spaces. for instance it will change "Warbinder's Ink" to "WarbindersInk"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

See comments for details.

```
Sub test()

    Dim rngTest     As Range

    '/ Add with  Workbook Scope. (This will fail due to incorrect naming)
    Set rngTest = Sheet1.Range("a5")
    Debug.Print "Name Added: " & addName(rngTest, "###Test_WB", True)

    '/ Add with worksheet Scope
    Set rngTest = Sheet1.Range("b5")
    Debug.Print "Name Added: " & addName(rngTest, "Test_WKS", False)

End Sub

Public Function addName(rngRangeTobeAdded As Range, strName As String, Optional bWorkbookLevel As Boolean = True) As Boolean

    Dim bResult     As Boolean
    Dim wbParent    As Workbook
    Dim wksParent   As Worksheet

    bResult = False

On Error GoTo errHandler

    If Not rngRangeTobeAdded Is Nothing And strName <> vbNullString Then
        '/ Set Parent containers
        Set wksParent = rngRangeTobeAdded.Parent
        Set wbParent = wksParent.Parent

        If Not bWorkbookLevel Then
            '/ Add Local
            wksParent.Names.Add strName, rngRangeTobeAdded
            bResult = True
        Else
            '/ Add Global
            wbParent.Names.Add strName, rngRangeTobeAdded
            bResult = True
        End If


    End If

errHandler:
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        bResult = False
    End If

    addName = bResult

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @cyboashu that did the trick. If only I had enough rep to to vote this up!